# PCL project not compiling after updating all the installed NuGet portable libraries

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, updates, portable-class-library

Everything was working fine in my Portable-Class-Library project until
I updated all the installed portable libraries.
It has stopped compiling. Throws the following errors for the nuget libraries installed.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference **`"System.Threading.Tasks"`** could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Runtime, Version=2.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7fd11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile104". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "System.Threading.Tasks" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime, Version=2.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7fd11d50a3a".
>
> 1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference **`"System.Net.Http.Extensions"`** could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Runtime, Version=2.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7fd11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile104". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "System.Net.Http.Extensions" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime, Version=2.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7fd11d50a3a".
>
> 1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference **`"Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions"`** could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Runtime, Version=2.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7fd11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile104". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime, Version=2.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7fd11d50a3a".
>
> 1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference **`"PCLStorage"`** could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Runtime, Version=2.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7fd11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile104". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "PCLStorage" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime, Version=2.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7fd11d50a3a".
>
> 1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference **`"Microsoft.Threading.Tasks"`** could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Runtime, Version=2.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7fd11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile104". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Microsoft.Threading.Tasks" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime, Version=2.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7fd11d50a3a".
>
> 1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference **`"System.Net.Http"`** could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Runtime, Version=2.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7fd11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile104". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "System.Net.Http" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime, Version=2.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7fd11d50a3a".
>
> 1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference **`"PCLStorage.Abstractions"`** could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Runtime, Version=2.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7fd11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile104". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "PCLStorage.Abstractions" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime, Version=2.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7fd11d50a3a".

How to point it to **`System.Runtime`** version 2.6.3.0?

Comment: There are certain profiles that simply don't support some of these items. Other than knowing your PCL is #104, have you tried other PCLs? Also possibly include a screenshot of your current items targeted?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AgHEgqqaasTkdDVMQWNURUNhSUdlZzV0Z2p3djlLQ3c&single=true&gid=3&output=html

Credit to @Cheesebaron

Comment: Actually I had updated all the installed nuget portable libraries.. Thats the cause of this problem and not VS update.. I updated libs immediately after the VS update..

Comment: @JonDouglas Thanks for that sheeet.. The profile used is 104 exactly matches all the target frameworks and libs supported.. all checks in the 104 row. All was fine.. and I update the VS, update the referenced nuget libs.. and it starts showing these errors

Comment: How to go back to using the previous version of these libs?

Comment: Well you can go back via a couple ways. 1. Change your PCL via Right clicking your solution and going to "Properties" and clicking "Change Targets". And 2. Remove references to BCL/custom items and start from scratch until you're onto something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the problem.

The PCL project's *app.config* was pointing to 2.6.3.0 version of `System.Runtime`. I changed it to point to 1.5.11.0, the previous one, and it compiled fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
   //   <!--  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.3.0" newVersion="2.6.3.0" /> -->
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.11.0" newVersion="1.5.11.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you try just removing all the binding redirects from the PCL's app.config?  Sometimes they get automatically added by NuGet when they're not needed for these packages.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your PCL version supports the dependencies you need. Here is a spreadsheet regarding the current support courtesy of CheeseBaron.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AgHEgqqaasTkdDVMQWNURUNhSUdlZzV0Z2p3djlLQ3c&single=true&gid=3&output=html

Note - Because this is still in it's infancy of supporting certain libraries, you'll have to find the right one that works for your project.

Comment: I fixed the problem by changing the System.Runtime version in PCL's app.config to older 1.5.11.0