# Xamarin core-project can't be buit after migrating from Mac to Win7

Tags: windows-7, xamarin, async-await, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I did my Xamarin project on mac, but now I need to migrate on Windows 7. It based on Mvvmcross, if it matters 
And a problem is, I can't build my Core part because of multiple errors like

> Error CS4001: Cannot await 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'
>   (CS4001)

when I cast

```
this.Error = await _loginService.Login (this.UserName, this.Password);
```

And no errors on Mac!

The PCL profile is 158. I tryed others (all of them, actually), but all the same. And, also, Microsoft.Bcl.Async package is installed too.

There are some warnings on Win7 (not on mac):

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(5,5):
>   Warning MSB3268: The primary reference "Microsoft.Threading.Tasks"
>   could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the
>   framework assembly "System.Runtime, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the
>   currently targeted framework.
>   ".NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile158". To resolve this
>   problem, either remove the reference "Microsoft.Threading.Tasks" or
>   retarget your application to a framework version which contains
>   "System.Runtime, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". (MSB3268)

and

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(5,5):
>   Warning MSB3268: The primary reference
>   "Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" could not be resolved because
>   it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly
>   "System.Runtime, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the
>   currently targeted framework.
>   ".NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile158". To resolve this
>   problem, either remove the reference
>   "Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" or retarget your application to
>   a framework version which contains "System.Runtime, Version=1.5.11.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". (MSB3268)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196552/pcl-project-not-compiling-after-updating-all-the-installed-nuget-portable-librar

Comment: There is some way, I found, wich helps to port the project, but it's not realy good solution.

I changed target profile to **78**, and it means I had to change all code, wich used Reflection in case Microsoft changed the way we should work with Types and Assemblies in 4.5 profiles. No it works OK, but there are some merging problems for my teammates, and changing target frameworks - not the best way, I believe